# Windows 10 still downloading updates over metered connection

Tags: windows-10, networking, windows-update

I have a desktop PC with Windows 10 Pro and connect to The Internet via a cable to my router.

I have set my connection to "metered" and told Windows Update to NOT download over metered connections.

That did nothing as some time ago some update(s) were forced on me postfactum. Meaning Windows had silently and sneakily downloaded them and just told me I need to restart to install them. Again with no option not to do so, I could postpone it, at best but when Windows' patience runs out it would force my computer to restart.

So I changed some Group Policies.

```
Policy                                                                                                          Setting         Winning GPO
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Allow updates to be downloaded automatically over metered connections                                           Disabled        Local Group Policy
Always automatically restart at the scheduled time                                                              Disabled        Local Group Policy
Configure Automatic Updates                                                                                     Disabled        Local Group Policy
Do not adjust default option to 'Install Updates and Shut Down' in Shut Down Windows dialog box                 Enabled         Local Group Policy
Enabling Windows Update Power Management to automatically wake up the system to install scheduled updates       Disabled        Local Group Policy
No auto-restart with logged on users for scheduled automatic updates installations                              Enabled         Local Group Policy
Turn on recommended updates via Automatic Updates                                                               Disabled        Local Group Policy
Turn on Software Notifications                                                                                  Disabled        Local Group Policy
```

Now even that doesn't help. Again I have a notification a (useless) update was downloaded and I must restart my computer to install it.

Is there a way to completely stop Windows 10 Pro from checking for updates?

Comment: You cannot disable Windows Update on Windows 10 Professional with a group policy.  Configuring your connection as a meter connection will prevent optional updates but not all updates

Comment: "Is there a way to completely stop Windows 10 Pro from checking for updates?"   <-  No. Not now, and not likely ever.